# How to name a collection of an interface?

Tags: .net, collections, interface, naming-conventions

The situation is as follows.

```
public interface IFoo { }

public abstract class FooBase : IFoo { }
```

Now I need a collection of `IFoo` with some additional methods.

```
public class IFooCollection : List<IFoo>
{
   public void UsefullMethod() { }
}
```

The problem is that `IFooCollection` looks like an interface while it is a class. The options are the following.

1. Keep it `IFooCollection` - I don't like this because it looks like an interface.
2. Name it `FooCollection` - I don't like this because it is not a collection of foos.
3. Turn it into `FooBaseCollection` because all implementations of `IFoo` derive from `FooBase` - I don't like this because this might not be true forever.
4. Don't create the class at all but provide extension methods for `IList<IFoo>` because there are only a hand full methods - I don't like this because changing the code because you cannot find a name for a class ... yes, that is nasty.
5. Something I did not think about or forgot to write it down - I hope I will like it!

So what would you do? Is there a naming convention I missed? We are basicaly using this [Microsoft .NET Library Standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71)(loband).aspx).

**UPDATE**

The code will not become widespread - it is just inside a GUI tool to put some data into a server. So I don't care about using the methods with other collections or overlooking the methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like `FooCollection` you have a collection of the conceptual object "Foo" even if there is not an actual `Foo` class or interface.  This is in keeping with `IFoo` is an interface of a "Foo" even if there is no `Foo` class. `SpecialFoo` would be a special kind of "Foo" even though there is no `Foo` class.

I definitely agree that `IFooCollection` is wrong because of the implied interface.

Answer (score 7):

FooCollection - it's not obvious with 'Foo' as Foo has no meaning, so it's difficult to conceptualise. Try it with a 'real' class/interface name and it makes more sense - e.g.

```
public class ErrorHandlerCollection : List<IErrorHandler>
{
  public void PublishErrors(){//...}
}
```

This makes sense because an ErrorHandlerCollection is a collection of error handlers. Anything that implements IErrorHandler IS an error handler, so anything in the ErrorHandlerCollection will be an error handler.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like #4 more than building your own collection type, because ultimately users are going to want to stuff their IFoo-implementing objects into their own lists and other collections.  This way, those collections will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have identified most of the choices really.

The only additional one I could think of is CollectionOfIFoo, but that is not in line with the conventions.

Id probably go with IFooCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the idea of using extension methods.  If you are worried about people being able to find the extension methods easily, just put them in a static class in the same code file as the IFoo interface.  Or create an "IFooExtensions" class in a separate file in the same namespace to make it easy to spot when people are looking at "IFoo"

Answer (score 0):

IMO #2 is the correct naming, though I would also suggest FooList since you're deriving from a List.

Answer (score 0):

How about `CollectionOfIFoo`?

Personally, I don't like the convention of prefixing interfaces with 'I' - it's basically a form of the bad kind of hungarian notation, and this is an example of why it's bad.